# Agglomerative clustering evaluation and fixing threshold

Tags: clustering

I'm new to clustering. recently I've implemented  agglomeration clustering, I understood that we merge clusters that have distance < Threshold.

1. But how to fix the Threshold?
2. How to choose right method for finding distance [euclidean, manhattan,..]?
3. How to evaluate my clusters?

Comment: Points 2 and 3 are so capacious that nobody will consider answering them. If you are new to clustering, please read books, or at least one, first. Point 1 is not clear - what you mean by threshold; aglomeration clustering algorithm does not use "thresholds".

Answer (score 1):

1. There are different strategies for extracting flat clusters. Thresholds are good when you have an intuition, e.g. "1 mile". Alternatively, you can choose the cut to get a desired number of clusters.

   The following publication may also be of use:

   Ricardo J. G. B. Campello, Davoud Moulavi, Arthur Zimek, Jörg Sander:
   **A framework for semi-supervised and unsupervised optimal extraction of clusters from hierarchies**
   Data Mining and Knowledge Discovery, Volume 27, Number 3 / November 2013.
2. Choose whichever distance function **works best** for your data. Spend at least as much time on preprocessing as on choosing the distance. There are no general rules of which is best. I have good experiences with using Canberra as default.
3. Read a book on this. There are way too many measures. Adjusted Rand Index is a good default choice, I guess. When using internal evaluation, make sure it is not closely related to your algorithms, because you can then overfit on the method side. E.g. K-means usually comes out best when you look at variances...

Comment: Thanks for a reference to the article, it can be found in the web.